# Riak: how are queries using secondary indices implemented?

Tags: riak

Consider a query that uses secondary indices. Does this cause the node that received the query to send out a request to all other nodes? That is, does the use of secondary indices require communicating with all other nodes to find data that matches the index lookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best source for information on how querying of secondary indexes works can be found here:

http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/2i/

I believe that the portion of the explanation that is relevant to your question is:

"When issuing a query, the system must read from a “covering” set of partitions and then merge the results. The system looks at how many replicas of data are stored—the N value or n_val—and determines the minimum number of partitions that it must examine (1 / n_val) to retrieve a full set of results, also taking into account any offline nodes."

Also note that: "For all 2i queries, the R parameter is set to 1," - http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/2i/#Querying